# Is it necessary to destroy/rebuild an existing VM to increase its memory?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I am trying to increase the RAM usage of my VM from 512MB to 4GB and have modified the vagrantfile to do exactly that:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vm.memory = "4096"
end
```

When rebooting the VM, calling `free-m` reveals that the total RAM has not changed. I've already done quite a bit of work in this environment and would hate to have to restart. Is there anyway to update the RAM while not deleting the environment?

(This issue arose when I ran out of memory for a JVM using MapReduce.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a typo issue, you define `vb` as the variable name but you're calling `vm.memory` you just need to align

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4096"
end
```

Comment: Much appreciated - guess I just needed another pair of eyes. As well, I ended up resolving this by altering the config in VirtualBox (it was necessary to launch as admin).